# Find $\lim_{x\to\infty} x\exp(1/x)-x$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Is there a way to find the $$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\exp(1/x)-x$$ but without using L'Hospital's rule??

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I don't understand the "on hold" think, since the question is COMPLETELY about mathematics and also it has already an answer...

Comment: So why don't you punt ON HOLD every single question in which is asked to find limit without using Hopital rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x\to \infty$ we can use Taylor Series for $e^{1/x}$:

$$e^{1/x}\approx 1 + \frac{1}{x}$$

Thence

$$x\left(1 + \frac{1}{x}\right) - x$$

So the limit is

$$\boxed{1}$$

Comment: Wow did not thought of using Taylor series...nice it's different

Answer (score 7):

Let $1/x=t$. We are interested in 
$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{e^t-1}{t}.$$
We recognize this limit (with no restrictions on direction) as the derivative of $e^t$ at $t=0$.

Answer (score 3):

As already said in answers, Taylor series is the most efficient way to solve the problem.

What is interesting is that, using one more term, you could see both the limit and how it is approached. $$e^{\frac{1}{x}}=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ $$xe^{\frac{1}{x}}-x=1+\frac{1}{2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ So, the limit is $1$ and it is approached from above.

Answer (score -1):

$$xe^{1/x}-x=x\left(e^{1/x}-1\right)=\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{\frac1x}$$

As $\;x\to\infty\;$ both numerator and denominator tend to zero so by l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{\frac1x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{1/x}=1$$

Comment: It's asked explicitly without using Hôpital rule :D

Comment: @1over137 Sorry, missed that. Yet all the other answers use either Taylor, which is as using derivatives as l'Hospital or more (among them the one you accepted), or the definition of derivative, which is derivatives, too. :D IMO the best answer is Andre's which at least uses the definition only of derivative. What's the difference between Taylor and l'Hospital from a point of view of using or not derivatives, or level of knowledge or whatever? I can't say.

Comment: I think that maybe it was an explicit request from the book or the professor.. Hospital rule can be very useful when you have more complicated function. whilst Taylor series is awesome when you have elementary functions.

Comment: @1over137. Taylor series always work even for very complex functions provided series compositions.